# Cancel out of FormView's Edit mode?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have a FormView with View and Edit modes, in an UpdatePanel:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:FormView runat="Server" DefaultMode="ReadOnly" DataSourceID="_myDataSource" >
            <ItemTemplate>

                <!-- View controls omitted -->
                <asp:Button runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" />
            </ItemTemplate>

            <EditItemTemplate>

                <!-- Edit controls omitted -->
                <asp:Button runat="server" CommandName="Update" Text="Save"  />
                <asp:Button runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" CausesValidation="false" />
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:FormView>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

 <!-- Data source (may attributes omitted) -->
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="_myDataSource" runat="server" />
```

The `Edit` and `Update` buttons / commands work fine, but the `Cancel` button does nothing.

Any ideas?

Comment: The FormView will simply come out of Edit mode on clicking cancel button. So what exactly you want the cancel button to do ?

Comment: That's what I want, but it doesn't do anything. Not even a postback. The "Edit" and "Update" buttons work as expected just by setting the `CommandName`.

Answer (score 2):

The page may not  seems to flicker but on clicking Cancel button 2 events are raised by FormView and post back indeed happens. You may refer [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.formview.itemcommand.aspx). ( Table under Remarks section)

What a 'Cancel' button does is:

`Cancels an edit or insert operation and returns the FormView control to the mode specified by the DefaultMode property. Raises the ModeChanged and ModeChanging events.`

So you need to handle events for ModeChanged and ModeChanging as shown below:

```
<asp:formview id="EmployeeFormView"
        datasourceid="EmployeeSource" allowpaging="true" datakeynames="EmployeeID"
        onmodechanged="EmployeeFormView_ModeChanged"  
        onmodechanging="EmployeeFormView_ModeChanging"
        runat="server">
```

So, any code that you want to run after ' cancel' button click should utilize these two events as per the requirements.

I had placed debugger in Page_Load, modeChanging() & modechanged(), all of the three events were fired in sequence on clicking 'Cancel' button.